# i am trying to implement a pair of AWS servers that use SSL to create self-signed certificates to communicate some data between them

Tags: openssl, ada

i am able to create a hello world sample program which simply communicating using AWS servers.

but now i am trying to use self signed certificates for communication over secure RSA 2048 connection. Can someone guide me how i can create self signed certificates in Ada and use it with in my server program.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                              Ada Web Server  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Com_1.adb
                            --
First launch Com_1 then Com_2.
--
--  Let's say that you will launch com_1 on computer1 and com_2 on
--  computer2. Then the commands to launch the demo are:
--
--  on computer1:
--    $ com_1 computer2
--
--  on computer2:
--    $ com_2 computer1
--

with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;

with AWS.Communication.Client;
with AWS.Communication.Server;
with AWS.Response;
with AWS.Utils;

procedure Com_1 is

   use Ada;
   use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
   use AWS;

   type String_Access is access all String;

   N    : Natural := 0;
   Wait : Boolean := True;

   Last_Message_Received : Boolean := False;

   function Receive
     (Server     : String;
      Message    : String;
      State      : not null access String;
      Parameters : Communication.Parameter_Set
        := Communication.Null_Parameter_Set)
     return Response.Data;
   --  Communication callback

   -------------
   -- Receive --
   -------------

   function Receive
     (Server     : String;
      Message    : String;
      State      : not null access String;
      Parameters : Communication.Parameter_Set
        := Communication.Null_Parameter_Set)
     return Response.Data is
   begin
      Wait := False;

      Text_IO.Put_Line ("Server " & Server
                        & " send me the message " & Message);
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("State " & State.all);


      Text_IO.New_Line;



      --return Response.Build ("text/html", "Ans [" & Utils.Image (N) & ']');
      return Response.Build ("text/html", "Hello");
   end Receive;

   Name : aliased String := "com_1, local server1";

   package Local_Server is
      new Communication.Server (String, String_Access, Receive);

   Answer : Response.Data;
K : Integer := 1;
begin
   if Command_Line.Argument_Count = 0 then
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("Usage: com_1 <computer>");
      return;
   end if;

   Local_Server.Start (1234, Name'Access);

   --  Wait for com_2 to become active
   while Wait loop
      delay 1.0;
   end loop;

   --  Send some messages

   --for K in 1 .. 10 loop
      Answer := Communication.Client.Send_Message
        (Command_Line.Argument (1), 3456, "mesSAGE" & Utils.Image (K),
         Communication.Parameters ("param1." & Utils.Image (K),
                                   "param2." & Utils.Image (K)));

      Text_IO.Put_Line ("< reply " & Response.Message_Body (Answer));
  -- end loop;

   --  Exit when last message received

   loop
      exit when Last_Message_Received;
      delay 3.0;
   end loop;

   Local_Server.Shutdown;

end Com_1;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_2.adb
---------

with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;

with AWS.Communication.Client;
with AWS.Communication.Server;
with AWS.Response;
with AWS.Utils;

procedure Com_2 is

   use Ada;
   use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
   use AWS;

   type String_Access is access all String;

   N : Natural := 0;

   Last_Message_Received : Boolean := False;

   function Receive
     (Server     : String;
      Message    : String;
      State      : not null access String;
      Parameters : Communication.Parameter_Set
        := Communication.Null_Parameter_Set)
     return Response.Data;
   --  Communication Callback

   -------------
   -- Receive --
   -------------

   function Receive
     (Server     : String;
      Message    : String;
      State      : not null access String;
      Parameters : Communication.Parameter_Set
        := Communication.Null_Parameter_Set)
     return Response.Data is
   begin
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("Server " & Server
                        & " send me the message " & Message);
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("State " & State.all);

      for K in Parameters'Range loop
         Text_IO.Put_Line ("   P" & Utils.Image (K) & " = "
                           & To_String (Parameters (K)));
      end loop;
      Text_IO.New_Line;

      N := N + 1;

      Text_IO.Put_Line ("================== " & Natural'Image (N));

      if N = 10 then
         Last_Message_Received := True;
      end if;

      return Response.Build ("text/html", "HELLO SERVER 1");
   end Receive;

   Name : aliased String := "com_2, local server1";

   package Local_Server is
      new Communication.Server (String, String_Access, Receive);

   Answer : Response.Data;
K: Integer := 1;
begin
   if Command_Line.Argument_Count = 0 then
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("Usage: com_2 <computer>");
      return;
   end if;

   Local_Server.Start (3456, Name'Access);

  -- for K in 1 .. 10 loop
      Answer := Communication.Client.Send_Message
        (Command_Line.Argument (1), 1234, "mes2." & Utils.Image (K));
      Text_IO.Put_Line ("< reply " & Response.Message_Body (Answer));
   --end loop;

   --  Exit when last message received

   loop
      exit when Last_Message_Received;
      delay 4.0;
   end loop;

   Local_Server.Shutdown;

end Com_2;
```

Comment: I think you need to show your work so far, e.g. these two programs communicate "hello world" between themselves; what do I add to do the same securely via SSL?

Comment: @BrianDrummond i have added the code.

Comment: @BrianDrummond i am also not aware how to self -signed the certificates. can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: got this link https://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/using_aws.html#secure-server and trying to configure how to self-signed certificates but didn't get success..

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/40851)? (I found it via Google "create self signed ssl certificate pem", but I think one of the links that StackOverflow has put on the right hand side of this page would have got you there quicker)

Comment: someone guide me on integrating Openssl with this code?